# Execute and renice a process in one command

Tags: command-line, priority, nice

Does anyone know if it's possible to execute and renice a process in one command, i.e. without having to look up the command in the list of processes using the ps command and then renice that particular pid.

Comment: Why don't you use `nice` when you launch the process, instead of `renice` afterwards?

Comment: @Glenn-jackman your post it is practically the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, @glenn-jackman gave you the answer. But just to elaborate a bit more, if you wish to give higher priority to the command but do not intend to run it as root, you could use a function (and sudo):

```
nice_cmd() {
  PRIORITY=$1 ; shift
  CMD=$1 ; shift
  ${CMD} $@ & cmdpid=$!
  sudo renice -n ${PRIORITY} -p ${cmdpid}
}
```

Then execute it as (this could ask for your user password, depending on how is sudo configured)

```
$ nice_cmd -5 vim somefile
$ fg
```

And from a top on another terminal, you can double check the nice value.

Comment: You always want to enclose `$@` in double quotes. You don't need to shift the command: `PRI=$1; shift; "$@" & pid=$1; ...`

Comment: Agreed, but it is just a good measure to be more specific on how it works.

Comment: Just interested in the two downvotes, any further reason why ?

Comment: because the nice command already does that. This being the accepted answer is just confusing.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `nice` (instead of `renice`). For example:

```
nice -n 10 command
```

This will run `command` with a low priority.

Answer (score -1):

Linux process scheduling using nice and renice commands with examples can also be found at http://www.vmexplore.com/tuning-process-scheduling/

Comment: It is better to provide action information here, and use the link as a reference for further details. That way your answer does not lose all of it value when the link becomes invalid.